# Is there an equivalent to `cabal-dev ghc`

Tags: haskell, cabal-dev

I'm learning to use a cabal-dev setup for projects to keep dependencies clean.  `cabal-dev ghci` and `cabal-deb ghc-pkg` work in nicely.  But I find myself wanting to issue a `cabal-dev ghc` command but it doesn't exist.

The context is trying to get flymake in emacs working using ghc but a straight `ghc` command doesn't pick up the cabal-dev environment.

Is there something that will give me `cabal-dev ghc` in the same way that `cabal-dev ghci` works?

Comment: Have you looked into hs-env?

Comment: Latest hsenv is now at https://github.com/tmhedberg/hsenv.  Looks good but haskell-mode has become cabal-dev centric and I wouldn't want to drift too far away from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you want doesn't exist yet. Please file a feature request: https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev/issues?state=open